# Processing form data with ENCTYPE

Tags: php, mysql, forms, enctype

By now I know to upload file form is using ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data. But when we want to transfer  form datat to mysql via php file what should be the enctpe=""?

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST" name="contactform"  onSubmit="return ValidateForm(this);  ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
```

Can we use ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" if not what should i use???

Please answer me

Thanks

Comment: unless your passing files through you shouldn't need to use enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: Processing is an open source programming language and environment for people who want to create images, animations, and interactions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to fill in a form enctype when you aren't using a file upload.
The default value is: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". (when enctype not provided)

Conclusion: leave empty or use "multipart/form-data" when you need to upload a file.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

Comment: thanks  i got my answer. if i  am satisfy with the answer what should i do?? I am new her. I think i can close this question if yes How??

Answer (score 1):

Basically ENCTYPE is the property of form. This is not necessory to use this property, it is optional.